# Spring Cloud Gateway asynchronous route predicate

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

The Spring Cloud Gateway is configured to use service discovery (Consul). The application.yml contains the following portion:

```
gateway:
  discovery:
    locator:
      enabled: true
      predicates:
        MyPredicate=
```

As a result the gateway automatically produces a route for every service registered in the Consul with MyPredicate.

In order to determine whether predicate's method test() should return true or false, I need to make an API call. Without going into much detail, consider the following example:

- Consul has MyService1 and MyService2 registered.
- An http request comes for a MyService/someResource.
- Depending on some conditions request should be forwarded to either MyService1/someResource or MyService2/someResource.
- To determine which of the two services needs to be called, an underlying API call has to be made.
- Only one route has to be selected. So if that underlying API call returns MyService1, then the corresponding route predicate has to return true while the predicate of MyService2 route has to return false.

While gateway filters are designed to be called asynchronously returning Mono<>, it looks like predicates are not designed the same way. It seems like a design flaw to me, but I might be missing something.

I would expect an asynchronous reactive predicate design with the Predicate.text() method returning Mono instead of primitive boolean. This way it could be chained with the rest of the reactive functionality.

I wonder if there's a way to create such a predicate. Otherwise, I'm required to use blocking API calls in an otherwise non-blocking gateway architecture.

Maybe there are alternatives other than Predicates to what we're trying to achieve?